# How to install SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) on an existing SQL Server Express install?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-express

I have [SQL Server 2005 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express), but I haven't got [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services) (SSRS). How do I install it separately? Do I have to download the whole SQL Server setup again, or is there any separate setup for only SSRS?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out the [SQL Server 2005 Express overview page](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-down.aspx): there are several versions of SQL Server Express - the basic version doesn't include Reporting Services - you need the SQL Server Express With Advanced Tools version to get Reporting Services.

Here's the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-down.aspx) for SQL Server **2005** Express - if you want Reporting Services, you need to get the "SQL Server 2005 Express Edition with Advanced Services SP3".

**Update:** this is the [SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx) overview page, from which you can also download the various SQL Server 2008 R2 Express versions. You will need the SQL [Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25174) which includes SSRS 2008.

Comment: sir, so there's no separate setup only for reporting services? i also googled it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @sqlchild: no, there is not, as far as I know. Reporting Services are part of SQL Server and can only be installed together with SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s: sir, do i need IIS also installed on my pc, to use reporting services of sql server express. i am having windows xp

Comment: @sqlchild: the SSRS 2005 version requires IIS, yes; that dependency has been removed with the SSRS 2008 versions which do **not** require IIS anymore

Comment: the download page, which you mentioned in your post, i downloaded it, but while installation , in the "Features to Install" option it doesn't show Reporting Services.